# Check if OU exists before creating it

Tags: validation, powershell, active-directory

```
function NyChildOU {
  $overOU = Read-Host "Type in the name of the parrent OU"
  $oucheck = [adsi]::Exists("LDAP://OU=$overOU,OU=PS,DC=PS,DC=local")
  if ($oucheck -eq "true") {
    $navnpaaou = Read-Host "Type in the name of the new OU"
    $oucheck2 = [adsi]::Exists("LDAP://OU=$navnpaaou,OU=$overOU,OU=PS,DC=PS,DC=local")
    if ($oucheck2 -eq "false") {
      New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $navnpaaou -path "OU=$navnpaaou,OU=$overOU,OU=PS,DC=PS,DC=Local"
      Write-Host "The new entry: $navnpaaou is created within $overOU"
    } else {
      Write-Host "OUen $navnpaaou do exist within $overOU"
    }
  } else {
    Write-Host "OUen $overOU doesen't exist, trie again"
  }
}
```

This is my script, the purpose of which is to create a OU unless it already exist. I just can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: What is wrong with it? What happens when you run it? What are you expecting?

Comment: it recognize that the parent OU exist, but insists that the child already is present

Comment: Change `-eq "true"` and `-eq "false"` to `-eq $true` and `-eq $false`

Comment: Did you change it in both places? `$true -eq "true"` will work as expected, but `$false -eq "false"` won't

Comment: oh, $false might be my problem? sorry, I'm quite new at this, and I do understand that the error-handling is pretty diverse

Comment: yes, tried all the combinations i could think off :S

Comment: i'm just not sure why if2 return a negative anyways

Comment: Can you post the error message you're getting back?

Comment: It only returns my own error-msg "Write-Host "OUen $overOU doesen't exist, trie again"" no matter what I do, it appears

Comment: I remember there being a bug with [adsi]::Exists("...") MS recommends you catch the exception and handle it (rather then they fix the bug)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply check if `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` returns an OU with that distinguished name and create it otherwise:

```
$parentOU = 'OU=parent,OU=PS,DC=example,DC=com'
$navnpaaou = Read-Host "Type in the name of the new OU"
$newOU = "OU=$navnpaaou,$parentOU"
if (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "distinguishedName -eq '$newOU'") {
  Write-Host "$newOU already exists."
} else {
  New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $navnpaaou -Path $parentOU
}
```

Comment: this works, but i wan't the code to return a error msg if the subOU already exist :)

Comment: and for some reason my double check with if-sets doesn't work

Comment: @Freshman Well, if you want an error message: just add an error message.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted answer and found that it would throw an exception if the OU didn't already exist. The following function tries to retrieve an OU, catches the thrown error if it doesn't exist, and then creates the OU.

```
function CreateOU ([string]$name, [string]$path, [string]$description) {
    $ouDN = "OU=$name,$path"

    # Check if the OU exists
    try {
        Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $ouDN | Out-Null
        Write-Verbose "OU '$ouDN' already exists."
    }
    catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
        Write-Verbose "Creating new OU '$ouDN'"
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $name -Path $path -Description $description
    }
}

CreateOU -name "Groups" -path "DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com" -description "What a wonderful OU this is"
```

Comment: As a note, I figured you could just use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, but this doesn't work for the AD powershell cmdlets, so this answer worked nicely.